# Display a Number, Convert Number, then Display Result as a quantity in special characters VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

Hi All:  I'm pretty green at VB.Net, and I'm having a tough time understanding the logic of transforming a number, then converting that number a string of characters equal to that number.

Example:

```
     Input = 1; Output as string using * is: * (4 asterisks, and etc.)
     Input = 3; Output as string using # is: ### (and so on).
```

Professor gave us this assignment to get sales amount from a user, then to display a type of bar graph with the info. * = $100.  So, $600 would equal ******.  I can get the information, but I'm lost on how to convert this.  Hope I'm making this clear as a good question!  Here's what I'm doing... already a got loop getting the info:

```
' The variables
    Dim dblValueA, dblSales, dblTotal As Double
    Dim dblValueB As Double = 1
    Dim strInput, strChgVal As String
    Dim strSymbol As String = "*"
    Dim strOutput As String
    ' get some input via a loop structure:
    Try


    For intCount As Integer = 1 to 5    ' Sales/Input for 5 Stores
    strInput = InputBox("place input here:")
        dblSales = CInt(strInput)
            dblTotal = dblSales
            dblValueA = (dblTotal/dblValueB)
            strChgVal = Cstr(dblValueA)
            strOutput = strChgVal
            strSymbol = strOutput

            lstOutput.Items.Add(dblValueA.ToString)

    Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

It works, I'm just lost on how to make to my output show as an actual quantity of input.  How does one do this?

Comment: I think I am not getting the question. if `*` = $100, then $600 = `******` (6 stars) and not `**` (2 stars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like using the string constructor overload, as suggested in [@David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593559/3043). However, as per my comment there I would add code like this:

```
Public Function ToTextBars(ByVal input As Decimal, ByVal marginalValue As Decimal, ByVal BarCharacter As Char) As String
    'Always use a Decimal, not Double or Integer, when working with money

    Return New String(BarCharacter, CInt(CDec(dblValueA)/marginalValue))
End Function
```

It's still a one-liner :) Then call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(ToTextBars(600d, 100d, "*"c))
```

or like this:

```
Dim result As String = ToTextBars(3d, 1d, "#"c)
```

And the result will be:

```
******
```

However, I suspect writing a loop in here is part of the objective of the assignment. Using the string overload would miss the point. In that case, I'd write it like this:

```
Public Function ToTextBars(ByVal input As Decimal, ByVal marginalValue As Decimal, ByVal BarCharacter As Char) As String
    If input < 0 Then input *= -1
    Dim charCount As Integer = 0

    While input > 0
         charCount += 1
         input -= marginalValue            
    End While

    Return New String(BarCharacter, charCount)
End While
```

You would call this function in the same way as the first. This still uses the string constructor overload, but it does not avoid the loop I expect your professor wants you to write.

One more point of style here. Where did you pick up the `str` and `dbl` prefix habit? Did your professor teach you that? This used to be popular back in the days of vb6 and it's predessors, before .Net. Now, this is no longer considered helpful, and Microsoft's own style guidelines specifically recommend against those prefixes. Point your professor to this link if he doesn't believe you:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
strSymbol = New String("*"c, CInt(dblValueA))
```

Comment: I'd add a `marginalValue` variable and a `/ marginalValue` to that expression, for the case in the question where each $100 is worth one *, so that $600 looked like ******. Otherwise this is perfect, +1

Comment: Yep. I was assuming here that `dblValueB` was filling that purpose, but more explicit is better, to be sure.